# how to use fsolve without starting guess

Tags: matlab

I want to develop a desktop application for solving system of linear and nonlinear equations.
I am thinking to use C# with Matlab. I never use matlab before but i am trying to learn for my project.

So, I am trying to use fsolve and i follow the example given on documentation of fsolve.

```
function F = myfun(x)
F = [2*x(1) - x(2) - exp(-x(1));
    -x(1) + 2*x(2) - exp(-x(2))];

**x0 = [-5; -5];           % Make a starting guess at the solution**
options=optimset('Display','iter');   % Option to display output
[x,fval] = fsolve(@myfun,x0,options)  % Call solver
```

Here in my case i don't know the starting guess i.e. x0

I just have n number of equation with n unknown. Please guide me what to do and how to proceed.

Some sample equations:

```
a * b = 10^-14
(a * d)/c = 10^-6.3
(a * e)/d = 10^-10.3
.
.
.
c+d+e = 2.3 * 10^-3
```

Comment: Why not using Microsoft Solver Foundation directly http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/solverfoundation?

Answer (score 5):

`fsolve` uses numerical methods to solve the system of algebraic equations - you absolutely need an initial guess to use `fsolve`. If you were to solve the equations analytically, you would need a linearization of the system (if it was nonlinear, and note that this may or may not give you good results) and you could use `mldivide` or an [LU factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) or some other matrix decomposition to quickly solve the system `Ax=b`.

You could potentially roll your own bounded root-finding method (golden section search, parabolic interpolation, etc) to get around the fact that you need an initial guess - the tradeoff here is (a) bounded root-finding methods take longer than unbounded methods that require initial guesses; and (b) you need to make sure your solution lies within the lower and upper bounds.

Simply put, there's no way to numerically specify a set of equations and solve it analytically, exactly - you should either solve the system analytically (which may not be possible - if it is, I suggest Mathematica over MATLAB if you require nonlinear systems to work without linearization) or have to be content with specifiying an initial guess or bounds.

In physically-motivated, engineering based systems I've seen, the zero vector is typically a good enough guess, but this should not be hard coded - and if you want to solve any arbitrary system, you shouldn't force users to use this as an initial guess.